# Php unit test when using Promise

Tags: php, promise, phpunit

I use the Promise by AWS SDK to save many files to S3 bucket. I fail to build the unit test for that.

My functions

```
function save($item, array $layers)
{
    $promises = [];
    foreach ($layers as $key => $layer) {
        $filename = $this->getS3Filename($item, $key);
        $promise = $this->s3Client->uploadAsync(
        );
        $promise = $promise->then(
            function () {
            },
            function ($reason) use ($item) {
                $this->logger->error("The promise to store file on S3 was rejected with {$reason} for item {$item->getId()}");
            }
        );
        $promises[] = $promise;
    }
    all($promises)->wait();
}
```

I get the following error:

> GuzzleHttp\Promise\RejectionException : The promise was rejected with
>   reason: Invoking the wait callback did not resolve the promise 
>   /Users/sela/PhpstormProjects/ziggy/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php:112
>   /Users/sela/PhpstormProjects/ziggy/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:75

when running my `phpunit`

The following is my unit test code:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);

    parent::setUp();
}

public function testSaveBatch()
{
    $this->logger
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('error');
    $this->s3Client = $this->getMockBuilder(S3ClientInterface::class)
        ->setMethods(['uploadAsync'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();
    $promise = $this->createMock(PromiseInterface::class);
    $promise
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('then')
        ->will($this->returnCallback([$this, 'promiseCallback']));

    $this->s3Client
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('uploadAsync')
        ->willReturn(
            $promise
        );

    $object = new Object(
    );
    $layers = ['123' => ''];
    $object->save($item, $layers);
}

/**
 * @return null|MockObject
 */
public function promiseCallback()
{
    $promise = $this->createMock(PromiseInterface::class);

    $fulfilledPromise = $this->createMock(FulfilledPromise::class);
    $fulfilledPromise
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('resolve')
        ->will($this->returnCallback($promise))
    ;

    return $fulfilledPromise;

}
```